# Has Many Through, Stack Level Too Deep?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm playing with my first has_many through relationship.  I have three models. Here they are.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :pools
   has_many :games,
            through: :pools
   end
```

~

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :users
     has_many :games,
            through: :users 
     end
```

~

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :pool
 end
```

Should this set up allow me to do the following in IRB?

```
u=User.first
u.games
```

When I do that, I get the following error.

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /Users/ShiftedRec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
Maybe IRB bug!
```

I should be able to do u.games, and u.pools?
it would also be nice to do a pool.users and pool.games.

How would I have to change my model set up so I can get access to those methods..?

I've been reading around but the has_many through is kind of confusing.

Here is my schema as well

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140408165647) do

create_table "games", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "pool_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "games", ["pool_id", "user_id"], name: "index_games_on_pool_id_and_user_id", unique: true

create_table "pools", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id" #vestige of old approach
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token",           unique: true

end
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were getting the error because your associations are defined incorrectly. Rails goofed up and went in recursion.

**Update your models `Pool` and `User` as below:**

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :games 
  has_many :users, 
    through: :games 
end    

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are: 
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  has_many :games 
  has_many :pools, 
    through: :games 
end
```

You are trying to create **M-M Relationship** between `User` and `Pool` through `Game`. 
Also, remove `user_id` from `pools` table as you already have association through join table `games`.

Also, since you are on `rails console`(not IRB) after making above changes, reload the rails environment in `console` using `reload!` command.

Read more about **[has-many-through-associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)** in Rails guides.